# HAL_CAN_Transmit_IT and HAL_CAN_Receive_IT simultaneously use problem

Tags: uart, stm32, can, stm32cubemx, hal-library

Synopsis: STM32 HAL Library functions `HAL_CAN_Transmit_IT` and `HAL_CAN_Receive_IT` can't be used simultaneously effectively without data loss risks.

Details:

When you build a receive/transmit cycle like below (simplified)

```
main() {
  HAL_CAN_Receive_IT();
  HAL_CAN_Transmit_IT();
}

HAL_CAN_RxCpltCallback() {
  HAL_CAN_Receive_IT(); // Rearm receive
}

HAL_CAN_TxCpltCallback() {
  HAL_CAN_Transmit_IT(); // Rearm transmit
}
```

In some situations `HAL_CAN_Receive_IT`/`HAL_CAN_Transmit_IT` drops with a busy state. This occurs because both of Transmit & Receive uses a lock via `__HAL_LOCK(hcan)`.

When you call `HAL_CAN_Transmit_IT` and interrupt `HAL_CAN_RxCpltCallback` occurs, the state is locked by `HAL_CAN_Transmit_IT` and rearm rx fails.

What is the solution to solve this?

I can't find an easy way now. In my opinion, a general mistake is the unified `HAL_CAN_StateTypeDef State` used for three independent flags - General CAN state, rx state, and tx state.

I think the solution is to split State for {State, rxState & txState} and never lock the same thing in both of Receive/Transmit.

For example, the current structure,

```
typedef enum
{
  HAL_CAN_STATE_RESET             = 0x00,  /*!< CAN not yet initialized or disabled */
  HAL_CAN_STATE_READY             = 0x01,  /*!< CAN initialized and ready for use   */
  HAL_CAN_STATE_BUSY              = 0x02,  /*!< CAN process is ongoing              */
  HAL_CAN_STATE_BUSY_TX           = 0x12,  /*!< CAN process is ongoing              */
  HAL_CAN_STATE_BUSY_RX           = 0x22,  /*!< CAN process is ongoing              */
  HAL_CAN_STATE_BUSY_TX_RX        = 0x32,  /*!< CAN process is ongoing              */
  HAL_CAN_STATE_TIMEOUT           = 0x03,  /*!< CAN in Timeout state                */
  HAL_CAN_STATE_ERROR             = 0x04   /*!< CAN error state                     */
}HAL_CAN_StateTypeDef;

typedef struct
{
  ...
  __IO HAL_CAN_StateTypeDef   State;      /*!< CAN communication state        */
  ...
}CAN_HandleTypeDef;
```

split to

```
typedef enum
{
  HAL_CAN_STATE_RESET             = 0x00,  /*!< CAN not yet initialized or disabled */
  HAL_CAN_STATE_READY             = 0x01,  /*!< CAN initialized and ready for use   */
  HAL_CAN_STATE_BUSY              = 0x02,  /*!< CAN process is ongoing              */


}HAL_CAN_StateTypeDef;

typedef enum
{
  HAL_CAN_TXRX_STATE_READY             = 0x01,
  HAL_CAN_TXRX_STATE_BUSY              = 0x02,
  HAL_CAN_TXRX_STATE_TIMEOUT           = 0x03,
  HAL_CAN_TXRX_STATE_ERROR             = 0x04
}HAL_CAN_TxRxStateTypeDef;

typedef struct
{
  ...
  __IO HAL_CAN_StateTypeDef     State;      /*!< CAN communication state        */
  __IO HAL_CAN_TxRxStateTypeDef RxState;    /*!< CAN RX communication state        */
  __IO HAL_CAN_TxRxStateTypeDef TxState;    /*!< CAN TX communication state        */
  ...
}CAN_HandleTypeDef;
```

But that is an awesome library modification. Maybe there exists a better solution?
The same problem affects the USART library, I think.

Answer (score 2):

For rearm RX you can use __HAL_CAN_ENABLE_IT(&hcan, CAN_IT_FMP0); // set interrupt flag for RX FIFO0.

```
void HAL_CAN_RxCpltCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef *CanHandle)
{
   __HAL_CAN_ENABLE_IT(CanHandle, CAN_IT_FMP0);

}
```

or

```
void HAL_CAN_RxCpltCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef *CanHandle)
{

  if (HAL_CAN_Receive_IT(CanHandle, CAN_FIFO0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    __HAL_CAN_ENABLE_IT(CanHandle, CAN_IT_FMP0);  // set interrupt flag for RX FIFO0 if CAN locked
  }
}
```

cause, for example, stm32f1xx_hal_can.c:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_CAN_Receive_IT(CAN_HandleTypeDef* hcan, uint8_t FIFONumber)
{
  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_CAN_FIFO(FIFONumber));

  if((hcan->State == HAL_CAN_STATE_READY) || (hcan->State == HAL_CAN_STATE_BUSY_TX))
  {
    /* Process locked */
    __HAL_LOCK(hcan);                 // <<----see define of __HAL_LOCK, this contains return command, wtf????????


    if(hcan->State == HAL_CAN_STATE_BUSY_TX) 
    {
      /* Change CAN state */
      hcan->State = HAL_CAN_STATE_BUSY_TX_RX;
    }
    else
    {
      /* Change CAN state */
      hcan->State = HAL_CAN_STATE_BUSY_RX;
    }

    /* Set CAN error code to none */
    hcan->ErrorCode = HAL_CAN_ERROR_NONE;

    /* Enable interrupts: */
    /*  - Enable Error warning Interrupt */
    /*  - Enable Error passive Interrupt */
    /*  - Enable Bus-off Interrupt */
    /*  - Enable Last error code Interrupt */
    /*  - Enable Error Interrupt */
    /*  - Enable Transmit mailbox empty Interrupt */
    __HAL_CAN_ENABLE_IT(hcan, CAN_IT_EWG |
                              CAN_IT_EPV |
                              CAN_IT_BOF |
                              CAN_IT_LEC |
                              CAN_IT_ERR |
                              CAN_IT_TME  );   
    /* Process unlocked */
    __HAL_UNLOCK(hcan);

    if(FIFONumber == CAN_FIFO0)
    {
      /* Enable FIFO 0 message pending Interrupt */   
      __HAL_CAN_ENABLE_IT(hcan, CAN_IT_FMP0);         // <<---- here the rearm interrupt flag for FIFO0, if can is locked, function exits on  __HAL_LOCK and newer comes here!
    }
    else
    {
      /* Enable FIFO 1 message pending Interrupt */
      __HAL_CAN_ENABLE_IT(hcan, CAN_IT_FMP1);
    }

  }
  else
  {
    return HAL_BUSY;
  }

  /* Return function status */
  return HAL_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a slave, you would use this as a listener-responder. As a master, you would use it as a transmitter-listener.

Point being is that at any moment, you know what you should be doing, either listening or transmitting.

I've found the ST HAL to be great for getting a running start, but if you diverge away from a few specific use cases it gets extremely hairy. I'm not sure how it matters in this case though, because CAN is half-duplex.

Comment: My application is "adapter". Must transfer anything without any limitations.

Comment: Half duplex means you can talk or you can receive. That is a physical limitation of CAN Bus.\

Answer (score 0):

`HAL_CAN_Transmit_IT` and `HAL_CAN_Receive_IT` work with interrupts. I would suggest you find the one that is more important for you and use the interrupt on that. For example, if you'd rather receive than transmit, use `HAL_CAN_Receive_IT` and `HAL_CAN_Transmit` for the transmit part.

With the way a CAN BUS works, you can get a message at any given time and therefore your receive interrupt will be very busy.

In my own implementation, I like to use the `HAL_CAN_Transmit` and the `HAL_CAN_Receive` functions without the interrupts, because my implementations do not use remote request frames and, so far, I did not have a need to actually use an interrupt to receive or transmit CAN messages.